# Excel 5 digit Datetime converted in SQL is 2 days ahead

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql, datetime

I have a spreadsheet with Datetimes as follows:

[image]

I am importing this file into an application so in Javascript I see the date being brought through as the normal 5 digit datetime code:

[image]

So far as I expect... However, when I then try getting this datetime readable in SQL Server, I run the following scripts:

```
select
    CONVERT(varchar(25),cast(28540 as datetime),121),
    dateadd(D,28540,0)
```

And the dates all return PLUS 2 days!

[image]

The same happens for all dates I pass through. I could easily just remove 2 from the 5 digit number but I don't want to just do that if there is a rule or reason for this?

Any advice on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Excel and SQL Server don't use the same algorithm for the dates. `0` in Excel is `1900/01/00` and `1` is `1900/01/01`. I also recall that it doesn't count `1900` as a leap year, causing a 2 digit difference.

Comment: Thanks for that insight Larnu....! So it is quite safe (standard practice) to hard-code the -2 into my Stored Procedures handling these dates then?

Comment: Provided you're working with recent(ish) dates, yes. Not if you're going back as far as dates prior to around 1905.

Comment: Haa - nope, all recent and future dates...! Good to know! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel dates are tricky. What they do is count the number of days since Dec 30th, 1899 (and early years are not entirely accurate).

One option is:

```
dateadd(d, 28540, '1899-12-30')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c0ecaa5ef21c4df7f215b5e761df6733)**:

```
 select dateadd(d, 28540, '1899-12-30') new_dt
```

```
| new_dt                  |
| :---------------------- |
| 1978-02-19 00:00:00.000 |
```

Comment: *"What they do is count the number of days since Dec 30th, 1899 "* I wish that were true, but it's really not. Have a look at the stupid behaviour in this [Office Online Excel Document](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AgJ9yD68a_NZnFJ06bomfV8NlcBX?e=lkhUc2). :(

Comment: @Larnu: yes their design is quite flawed... Basically it works fine for not-so-old dates...